# How to install AMD legacy drivers in Ubuntu 12.04.3

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, 12.04

I have a AMD 4xxx Series graphics card on my laptop. Ubuntu 12.04 is the last iteration of Ubuntu which had support of proprietary AMD Legacy Drivers. However, upon downloading the latest LTS release Ubuntu 12.04.3, I found that that support has gone too. Is there a way to install proprietary drivers again?

The laptop in its current form is overheating badly. Is there any other flavor of ubuntu which still supports the proprietary drivers?

Comment: someone answer please

Comment: It seems that support for AMD legacy drivers has gone. However Mint 13 LTS still has support for them so I'm using it currently.

Answer (score 1):

I think the latest driver is version 8.960 for AMD 4xxx Series graphics card and available from Ubuntu Package archive for distribution Precise:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=fglrx&searchon=names&suite=precise&section=all

- Download the two packages:

  fglrx
  fglrx-amdcccle
- Remove old `fglrx` and reboot the OS
- Install the two DEBs with `dpkg -i`

Comment: [This wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver) page may be useful...